How do I group rows based on 3 columns according to the following in R



Account
Tier 1
Tier 2
Tier 3




Account 1
1
21
55


Account 2
1
21
55


Account 3
2
52
72


Account 4
2
52
66


Account 5
3
52
66


Account 6
3
52
99


Account 7
4
63
43


Account 8
4
63
49


Account 9
5
36
94


Account 10
5
42
55



How do I group the accounts based on all 3 tiers according to the following?
If Account A & B are in the same group in Tier 1 and if Account 1, 2 & 10 are in the same group in Tier 3, then Account 1, 2, 9 & 10 need to be classified in the same final group. Account 9 was included because it groups with Account 10 in Tier 1.
Desired output:



Account
Tier 1
Tier 2
Tier 3
Final Group




Account 1
1
21
55
Group 1


Account 2
1
21
55
Group 1


Account 3
2
52
72
Group 2


Account 4
2
52
66
Group 2


Account 5
3
52
66
Group 2


Account 6
3
52
99
Group 2


Account 7
4
63
43
Group 3


Account 8
4
63
49
Group 3


Account 9
5
36
94
Group 1


Account 10
5
42
55
Group 1



This is a simplified version of a bigger problem which has 7+ tiers across 500k data points.

Another example where graph theory and the igraph package comes in handy, to find the connected components:
## make a two-column 'edgelist' showing the account<-->tier relationships
datlong <- cbind(dat[1], stack(dat[-1]))

library(igraph)
## make a graph object
g <- graph_from_data_frame(datlong[1:2])
## extract the connected components
cmp <- components(g)
## assign the membership of the accounts based on the components
dat$final_group <- cmp$membership[match(dat$Account, names(cmp$membership))]

dat
#     Account Tier1 Tier2 Tier3 final_group
#1   Account1     1    21    55           1
#2   Account2     1    21    55           1
#3   Account3     2    52    72           2
#4   Account4     2    52    66           2
#5   Account5     3    52    66           2
#6   Account6     3    52    99           2
#7   Account7     4    63    43           3
#8   Account8     4    63    49           3
#9   Account9     5    36    94           1
#10 Account10     5    42    55           1

Where dat was:
dat <- read.table(text="Account  Tier1  Tier2  Tier3
Account1  1  21  55
Account2  1  21  55
Account3  2  52  72
Account4  2  52  66
Account5  3  52  66
Account6  3  52  99
Account7  4  63  43
Account8  4  63  49
Account9  5  36  94
Account10  5  42  55", header=TRUE)

